# контейнер map c++

Tags: c++, map, счетчики

Как использовать контейнер map, для хранения счетчиков?

Comment: Счетчиков чего? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вот вам пример для проверки распределения случайных чисел - как счетчик количества значений `rand()%10`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    map<int,int> m;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        m[rand()%10]++;
    for(auto x: m)
        cout << x.first << " : " << x.second << endl;
}
```

Он же тут: http://ideone.com/AjKzi9
Устраивает?